# Constrained oscillator on an $n$-sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, oscillators

I have a particle in $n + 1$ dimensional space, whose components satisfy the equations $$\ddot{x}_i+\omega^2_ix_i =0. $$ 
and  I want to calculate the constraining force $F(\vec{x})$ that holds the particle on the $n$-sphere of radius 1 and write the equations of motion for the constricted oscillator (assuming $\vec{F}$ parallel to $\vec{x}$).

All I could do was write the expression:
$$F\cdot \vec{e}_i=m\ddot{x}_i=-\omega^2_ix_i.$$
I'm not really sure how to proceed

Comment: isn't that kinda the answer? can you solve it for $n=1$?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write your problem in the [n-dimensional spherical coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates), then since your constraint is only on the radius (the particle is free to move on all the angles) your equation becomes:

$$\ddot{r}+\omega^2r =0$$

that is easily solvable.